# Git requires username and password for git push, git pull using HTTPS method

Tags: linux, git, git-push, git-pull, git-clone

So, when I use HTTPS method for cloning git repository and do some changes and `push` or `pull` to git it will always be prompting me for `username and password`. what's the solution for that?

Comment: I found the solution!

Comment: What do you mean by "resolve this"? What are you asking?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice now it's ok?

Comment: What kind of solution do you want? What would you rather do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from changing to SSH, you can also keep using HTTPS, if you don't mind to put your password in clear text. Put this in your ~/.netrc and it won't ask for your username/password (at least on Linux and Mac)

Make one `.netrc` file in your home directory.

```
machine github.com
        login <user>
        password <password
```

Comment: What do you mean by don't mind putting password in clear text? Do you mean netrc uses cleartext?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is this git command which is kind of remember me of GIT.

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Read this for details:
[GIT credentials store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store/1.7.12.1)